# ios - Making a Calendar. Year view is really slow. Lots of subviews

Tags: ios, performance, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm making a calendar and the year view in particular, and understandably, is quite slow when coming into view.

The year view is simply a UICollectionView, and each month is a custom UICollectionViewCell XIB. The month has a title UILabel, and 7 dayName UILabels, and 42 dayNumber UILabels.

That's a total of 50 UILabels per month X 12. Aieesh...

How do other iOS calendar apps handle showing so many subviews without degradation in performance? The performance hit is mainly when swiping this view to the next and previous years. As the view is sliding in, the collection view is propagating the cells, causing the slow-down. I could hold off on populating the cells until the scrolling has stopped, but I'd really like to not show a white view as it's scrolling into the window.

Edit* As requested - my cellForRow method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSIndexPath *indexPathPlusOne = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];

    EICalendarYearViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"EICalendarYearViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (_datesLoaded == YES)
    {
        //Get First Day in Month
        NSMutableArray *arrayForDatesInMonth = [_dictHoldingArrayForEachMonth objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithLong:indexPathPlusOne.row]];
        NSDate *firstDayInMonth              = arrayForDatesInMonth[0];
        NSDateComponents* comp               = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSCalendarUnitWeekday)  fromDate:firstDayInMonth];

        //setting month label
        switch (indexPathPlusOne.row) {
            case 1:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"January";
                break;

            case 2:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"February";
                break;

            case 3:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"March";
                break;

            case 4:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"April";
                break;

            case 5:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"May";
                break;

            case 6:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"June";
                break;

            case 7:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"July";
                break;

            case 8:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"August";
                break;

            case 9:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"September";
                break;

            case 10:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"October";
                break;

            case 11:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"November";
                break;

            case 12:
                cell.labelTitle.text = @"December";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        //setting number of days in previous month to show.
        long previousMonthDays = 0;
        if (comp.weekday == 7)
        {
            previousMonthDays = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            previousMonthDays = comp.weekday - 1;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < cell.arrayOfDayLabels.count; i++)
        {
            UILabel *labelDay = cell.arrayOfDayLabels[i];

            //previous Month days
            if (i <= previousMonthDays)
            {
                labelDay.text = @" ";
                labelDay.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1.000];
            }

            //Actual days in current month
            if (i >= previousMonthDays && i < previousMonthDays + arrayForDatesInMonth.count)
            {
                NSDate *dateForDay = arrayForDatesInMonth[i - previousMonthDays];
                NSDateComponents *compsForDay = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:dateForDay];
                labelDay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)compsForDay.day];
                labelDay.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            }
            else
            {
                labelDay.text = @" ";
                labelDay.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1.000];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cell.arrayOfDayLabels.count; i++)
        {
            UILabel *labelDay = cell.arrayOfDayLabels[i];
            labelDay.text = @" ";
        }
    }

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    [cell.layer setRasterizationScale:3.0f];

    return cell;
}
```

For rmaddy, a screenshot of the methods causing majority of slow-down.

[image]

Comment: The performance is unlikely due to the number of views. It's most likely due to all of your date calculations to populate the views. Use Instruments to see the real cause of the performance issues.

Comment: Can you share the code of your method `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`
?

Comment: Emilie, I added my cellForItem method. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: rmaddy, I tried setting a dispatchAfter delay of 4 seconds so that the dates would not be loaded until after the view had definitely appeared and stopped scrolling, but the janky scrolling still occurs as the view slides into window (with default label values). In instruments, I've got 4 methods causing ~85% of the slow-down. I'll post a screenshot of what those are.